# Kill session in AWS Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, oracle12c

I have a AWS Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release DB,
I want to kill a session using the Master username.

```
set role dba;
alter user MY_MASTER_USER default role connect, dba;
```

But when I run `alter system kill session '14,60599';` from `MY_MASTER_USER` user I got this error:

```
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little googling gave me this:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.System.html#Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.KillingSession

```
begin
    rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.kill(
        sid    => sid, 
        serial => serial_number);
end;
/
```